# MediaFormatter or ModelBinder for web api PUT method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

I have a PUT method in web api which accepts a JSON data and a route data as follows.

```
[Route("api/v1/Orders/{orderId}/active")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(Guid? orderId,List<ActiveRequest> activeRequests)
    {


    }
public class ActiveRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } 
}
```

Now is it possible to simplify the method signature as:

```
[Route("api/v1/Orders/{orderId}/active")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(ActiveRequestModel model)
    {


    }
public class ActiveRequestModel
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<ActiveRequest> ActiveRequests {get; set;} 
}
```

I tried writing a custom ModelBinder by implementing the System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder interface but could'nt find a way to read the JSON data that is coming inside the Request object. 
I doubt that is there a way by which I can bind my model with data coming from three different places i.e. from ***route data, json & form***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simplify the parameter as described.

Unlike MVC model binding, beacuse of how the Web API formatter works, in Web API you only can have a single parameter that is deserialized from the payload, and a number of simple type parameters coming from route parameters or url query string. The reason is that the creation of the parameter coming from the payload is done in a single pass deserialization of the payload.

So, for your example you need the two parameters in your original version, i.e.:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(Guid? orderId, List<ActiveRequest> activeRequests)
```

If you want to use the `ActiveRequestModel` you need to include a payload which has exactly the same structure, so you should include the `orderId` in the payload, because it will not be recovered from the url (even if the name matches).

Please, read this article which explains how parameter binding works in Web API:

- [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

If you read it thoroughly you'll see that you can create and register your own model binder to make it work the same way that an MVC controller, but I think it's not worth the effort (so I include it only in this last paragraph), and it's not the standard way of working.

Comment: Thanks @JotaBe, but my OrderId won't be a part of the JSON payload. It will be coming from the route. like my url will have that data exp: http://localhost:12345/api/v1/Orders/A8428935-85BC-4A05-BB33-DDB9D5FF2D53/active

Comment: @thinkmmk I'm sorry I didn'd understand you question. I've fully edited my answer now. You cannot do what you want, unless you include the order id in the payload, or define an use your own model binder

Comment: thanks again for clarifying the same,  so  a custom model binder can fulfill my requirements or do i have to include the orderid inside json?

Comment: It's up to you: if you think that you can easyly implement a model binder which solves most of your bindings, then do it. If you think that you'll have to create lots of different model binders, or the implementation it's difficult, take the easy path, and include it in the JSON, which is pretty easy. I'm not discouraging to do it, but warning you that if it gets too complicated it's better to do it the "usual way".

Comment: But again i have the same doubt,  will i be able to read data from post n route data together inside my model binder.  If yes which property exposes those.

Comment: There are several properties to get the raw JSON data from the request, for example `Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. Then you can use JSON.NET to deserialize it. Implementing the Model Binder is complex because you only have access to the raw data, and the headers to determine which kind of data is being posted. Your model binder has to determine if it's JSON to deserialize as JSON, or is form data, to read it as form data, or is any other format to read it. Quite complex. That's why I commented that probably it's not worth the effort.